# Generate Ant build file

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

I have the following project structure:

```
root/
    comp/
        env/
           version/
                  build.xml
           build.xml
        build.xml
```

Where **root/comp/env/version/build.xml** is:

```
<project name="comp-env-version" basedir=".">
    <import file="../build.xml" optional="true" />
    <echo>Comp Env Version tasks</echo>
    <target name="run">
        <echo>Comp Env Version run task</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

**root/comp/env/build.xml** is:

```
<project name="comp-env" basedir=".">
    <import file="../build.xml" optional="true" />
    <echo>Comp Env tasks</echo>
    <target name="run">
        <echo>Comp Env run task</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

**root/comp/build.xml** is:

```
<project name="comp" basedir=".">
    <echo>Comp tasks</echo>
</project>
```

Each build file imports the parent build file and each child **inherits** and **overrides** parent tasks/properties.

**What I need is to get the generated build XML without run anything**.

For example, if I run "ant" (or something like that) on root/comp/env/version/, I would like to get the following output:

```
<project name="comp-env-version" basedir=".">
    <echo>Comp tasks</echo>
    <echo>Comp Env tasks</echo>
    <echo>Comp Env Version tasks</echo>
    <target name="run">
        <echo>Comp Env Version run task</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Is there an Ant plugin to do this? With Maven? What are my options if not?

**EDIT:**
**I need something like "mvn help:effective-pom" for Ant.**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish though? Does Comp = Component & Env = Environment? Are you trying to build Environment-specific builds of various components?

Comment: Yep, something like that. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Something like "mvn -Doutput=<filename> help:effective-pom" but for Ant. mmmmm I don't remember seeing something like that.

Comment: I was just wondering if I could do this with maven, I was aware of that "help:effective-pom" goal. It's an option, thoughs?

Comment: If that's your goal (environment-specific builds of components), you probably want to stay *away* from Maven. Maven has a design goal of protecting you from environmental dependencies, which you'd have to work around.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the description of the [import task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html), it works very much like an entity includes with two additional features:

- target overriding
- special properties

For the purposes of viewing the "effective build" I don't think the special properties processing is required (though it could be added by iterating the inserted targets). So the processing to achieve this becomes.

1. Parse the build.xml to a DOM

   - For each top-level include tag found (only top-level are allowed), find the referenced source file.
   - Parse the referenced build.xml
   - insert any content from the referenced build.xml that don't collide with those in the current file.
   - Repeat step 2 for referenced build.xml file(s) until no more found
   - Output the resultant DOM

You can define a custom Ant task so that this processing can be defined in a task to be run from within your build. See this [tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) for more details.

Here's a basic implementation that recurses through imports and inserts the DOM elements from the referenced files. There's almost certainly a few bugs in it as I threw it together, but it should do largely what you're after:

```
/**
 * Reads the build.xml and outputs the resolved build to stdout
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Element root = new EffectiveBuild().parse(new File(args[0]));

        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        outputter.output(root, System.out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO handle errors
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Get the DOM for the passed file and iterate all imports, replacing with 
 * non-duplicate referenced content
 */
private Element parse(File buildFile) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    Element root = getRootElement(buildFile);

    List<Element> imports = root.getChildren("import");

    for (int i = 0; i < imports.size(); i++) {
        Element element = imports.get(i);

        List<Content> importContent = parseImport(element, root, buildFile);

        int replaceIndex = root.indexOf(element);

        root.addContent(replaceIndex, importContent);

        root.removeContent(element);
    }

    root.removeChildren("import");

    return root;
}

/**
 * Get the imported file and merge it into the parent.
 */
private List<Content> parseImport(Element element, Element currentRoot,
        File buildFile) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    String importFileName = element.getAttributeValue("file");
    File importFile = new File(buildFile.getParentFile(), importFileName)
            .getAbsoluteFile();
    if (importFileName != null) {
        Element importRoot = getRootElement(importFile);

        return getImportContent(element, currentRoot, importRoot,
                importFile);
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}

/**
 * Replace the passed element with the content of the importRoot 
 * (not the project tag)
 */
private List<Content> getImportContent(Element element,
        Element currentRoot, Element importRoot, File buildFile)
        throws JDOMException, IOException {

    if (currentRoot != null) {
        // copy all the reference import elements to the parent if needed
        List<Content> childNodes = importRoot.cloneContent();
        List<Content> importContent = new ArrayList<Content>();

        for (Content content : childNodes) {
            if (content instanceof Element
                    && ((Element) content).getName().equals("import")) {
                importContent.addAll(parseImport((Element) content,
                        currentRoot, buildFile));
            }
            if (!existsInParent(currentRoot, content)) {
                importContent.add(content);
            } else {
                // TODO note the element was skipped
            }
        }

        return importContent;
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}

/**
 * Return true if the content already defined in the parent
 */
private boolean existsInParent(Element parent, Content content) {
    if (content instanceof Text) {
        if (((Text) content).getText().trim().length() == 0) {
            // let the pretty printer deal with the whitespace
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (content instanceof Element) {
        String id = ((Element) content).getAttributeValue("name");

        String name = ((Element) content).getName();
        List<Content> parentContent = parent.getChildren();

        if (id != null) {
            for (Content content2 : parentContent) {
                if (content2 instanceof Element
                        && ((Element) content2).getName().equals(name)) {
                    String parentId = ((Element) content2)
                            .getAttributeValue("name");

                    if (parentId != null && parentId.equals(id)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Parse the passed file.
 */
private Element getRootElement(File buildFile) throws JDOMException,
        IOException {
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    builder.setValidation(false);
    builder.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    Document doc = builder.build(buildFile);

    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse understands Ant files.  You can see what tasks are visible in your inner build.xml.  It won't be quite the format you requested, but it may meet your needs.

Comment: Interesting, but I need to make that build file automaticaly, from the command line for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been writing Ant build scripts for 7-8 years now but I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve here.  Maybe it's me but I fear that even if you get your build working (I'm sure you can), hardly anyone else will understand/maintain it.

Why not keeping things very simple and having sibling projects?

```
root
    build.xml
    comp
        build.xml
    env
        build.xml
    version
        build.xml
```

individual `build.xml` files could import tasks define somewhere else (use Macrodef for this) and your top level `build.xml` would call the individual ones sequentially?

Once you get your basic build running, you can play around with Ivy or Maven for more interesting stuff.

But if you *really* want to generate build files, you can give Groovy and its templating engine a try.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm looking for is to generate the result build.xml of a "version" (in this case). Somethig like "mvn help:effective-pom" for Ant.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend structuring your build files so that they use a dependency tree which is what ant is really good at.  If you follow @Vladimir's advice and structure your build files like that, then you can have a single build file in 'root' and have it recursively execute your build.  For example:

```
<!-- iterate finds all build files, excluding this one
     and invokes the named target 
-->
<macrodef name="iterate">
    <attribute name="target"/>
    <sequential>
        <subant target="@{target}">
            <fileset dir="." 
                     includes="**/build.xml"
                     excludes="build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>


<target name="build"  description="Build all sub projects">
    <iterate target="build"/>
</target>

<target name="clean"  description="Clean all sub projects">
    <iterate target="clean"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Good advice, but is not what I'm looking for.
I need to generate a XML build file inheriting all build.xml files from parents.
I don't want to build the project, I want to get the generated build file for your example.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation / example for the subant task - http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/subant.html  - if your includes in your macrodef looks like "**/version/build.xml" and you set things up 'just so' you should be able to use the xslt task and the common2master.xsl to write out a master build file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [gradle](http://www.gradle.org) could help you. Gradle is able to [import your ant build.xml file](http://www.gradle.org/0.8/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#N110EB).
Then you can start a [dry run](http://www.gradle.org/0.8/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#N107CE) to get a list of targets that *would* be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script/app in Java, Groovy, Ruby or whatever you know best... the script would parse the xml of the build files and replace "over-ridden" targets with their overrides by actually swapping out the appropriate DOM Nodes. What you will end up with is your composite build.xml as a DOM which can then be serialized out.

You could keep the script on hand in your source control so that you can regenerate as needed.

This may sound a bit extreme but it sounds like most other solutions are out of the scope of what you are looking for.

NOTE: You can run some scripting langs from Ant, so you could still use And as your initiator.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually see Rich Sellers post... I didnt see that one... he beat me to the idea.