# Dynamically finding build files with <ant> task

Tags: ant, build-automation

I am trying to build subprojects from my main Ant build script..

The build files are located in

```
plugings/<pluginName>/build.xml
```

I want to do something effectively like

```
<ant antfile="plugins/*/build.xml" ...>
```

It should dynamically find build files in the plugin directory. Haven't been able to get it to work yet with filesets.. any tips?

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:** `<subant>` was the task I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links show you a way of building sub-projects:

[Sample Ant build file for multiple projects](http://www.javawhat.com/showWebsiteContent.do?id=525427)

[Ant Tip 1: Write a master build file](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/ant-tip-1-write-a-master-build-file/)

Check this answer:

[Generate Ant build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469786/generate-ant-build-file/1494659#1494659)

Comment: yes, but what I want is to be able to use patterns for the filenames/path to build files. I want it to dynamically build all the plugins as they are added